# No puedo visualizar los resultados en sql shell

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Creé un usuario llamado `empleado_test` y le asigné el rol de `emp`, dicho rol tiene permisos para ejecutar una función, que es `buscar_pelicula(nombre_pelicula text)`. Me logro conectar al usuario `empleado_test` desde `sql shell` y lo verifico con el comando `\conninfo`, pero el problema es que no sé como puedo ejecutar la función `buscar_pelula` ni como ver el resultado en `sql shell`.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ejecutar la función incluyéndola en una sentencia select, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT buscar_pelicula('Titanic');
```

Esto te mostrará el resultado de la función en la fila de resultado del select.